# need fix Tkinter Error

Tags: tkinter

I have my windows
Wtere this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk' ???

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(428, 285)
root.maxsize(428, 285)
root.resizable(width=NO, height=NO) 
root.title("TEST")
root.wm_iconbitmap('C:\Python27\iconfile.ico')


# create the canvas, size in pixels
canvas = Canvas(width = 428, height = 255, bg = 'gray95')

# pack the canvas into a frame/form
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\Python27\image.gif')

# put gif image on canvas
# pic's upper left corner (NW) on the canvas is at x=50 y=10
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif1, anchor = NW)

def die(event):
    root.destroy()

b = Button(root, text="text")
b.bind("<Button-1>", die)
b["command"] = die
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you posted does not give the error you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like "NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'", it means somewhere in your code you have something that looks like `foo.tk()`, and `foo` is not defined. Look for that line of code and figure out why `foo` is not defined. Maybe you misspelled it, maybe you are calling it in the wrong order, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing:
`root = Tkinter.Tk()`
Sometimes, you need to call upon Tkinter for the program to understand where Tk() is from.